# Delete Image file in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a ListView with a DataTemplate that contains an Image Control. For each entry in the ListView the user can launch a second Page to edit the entry. There the user has the possibility to delete the image file associated to the entry. The image file is stored in the LocalFolder of the app.

The Image control has a "funny" behaviour when it comes to image loading. When settings its source via a BitmapImage and using a memory stream:

```
bitmapImage.SetSource(stream))
```

then everything behaves well and I can delete the file. However, when settings the source to an URI:

```
bitmapImage.UriSource = "ms-appdata:///local/myfile.jpg"
```

then I cannot delete the file (Access denied, the Image control of the ListView won't release the file).

in Windows Phone 8 there was the Onload CacheOption that prevented this behavior, but there is no such thing in WP8.1 with the Windows Runtime. Anyway, I do fear performance problems when loading all the images at once...

Do you have any suggestions how to accomplish the deleting of files?

thanks

Comment: One straightforward workaround would be to clear the UriSource of the BitmapImage of the selected item when navigating to the editing page, then restoring it when coming back to the page if the item hasn't been deleted.

Comment: Nice workaround indeed. I've done it and it works as expected. Thanks